# How to combine max-width, min-width in matchMedia query?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, matchmedia

I am working with the [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) API to determine viewports within javascript, so I can minimize the amount of dom manipulation taking place.

Instead of using `display: none` everywhere I determine if elements are inserted into the DOM or not with a `v-if` directive from Vue.

I have set it up like this:

```
resize() {
    this.mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches;
    this.tablet = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches;
    this.desktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches;
}
```

The mobile matchmedia query is fine but how do I determine exactly what is tablet size? I am wondering if I can combine `max-width` and `min-width` values within the matchMedia query.

Of course I could do something like this:

```
resize() {
    this.mobile = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches;
    this.desktop = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches;
    this.tablet = !this.mobile && !this.desktop;
}
```

I am wondering is this is properly set up like this though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just combine the media queries as you would do in CSS:

`this.tablet = window.matchMedia('(min-width:767px) and (max-width: 992px)');`